# Closing value grouping by last week's data

Tags: python

I'm working on the base below, and I need to group the close variable, grouping the last day of each week, by month and year, the base I'm working on has data from 2005 to 2017, below I'm just leaving a sample.

```
date        close   year   month  day    quarter      week
2016-12-23   961    2016    12    23      4        51
2016-12-22   928    2016    12    22      4        51
2016-12-21   926    2016    12    21      4        51
2016-12-20   914    2016    12    20      4        51
2016-12-19   927    2016    12    19      4        51
2016-12-16   946    2016    12    16      4        50
2016-12-15   966    2016    12    15      4        50
2016-12-14   1003   2016    12    14      4        50
2016-12-13   1052   2016    12    13      4        50
2016-12-12   1069   2016    12    12      4        50
2016-12-23   934    2017    12    23      4        51
2016-12-22   928    2017    12    22      4        51
2016-12-21   926    2017    12    21      4        51
2016-12-20   914    2017    12    20      4        51
2016-12-19   927    2017    12    19      4        51
2016-12-16   933    2017    12    16      4        50
2016-12-15   966    2017    12    15      4        50
2016-12-14   1003   2017    12    14      4        50
2016-12-13   1052   2017    12    13      4        50
2016-12-12   1069   2017    12    12      4        50
```

Grouping should look like this.

```
date       close    year    month     day     quarter   week
2016-12-23  961     2016      12      23       4         51
2016-12-16  946     2016      12      16       4         50
2017-12-23  934     2017      12      23       4         51
2017-12-16  933     2017      12      16       4         50
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can so this without using `groupby`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['year', 'month','quarter', 'week' , 'day']).drop_duplicates(['year', 'month','quarter', 'week'] , keep ='last')
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
          date  close  year  month  day  quarter  week
5   2016-12-16    946  2016     12   16        4    50
0   2016-12-23    961  2016     12   23        4    51
15  2016-12-16    933  2017     12   16        4    50
10  2016-12-23    934  2017     12   23        4    51
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby with idxmax

```
df.set_index('date').groupby(['week', 'year']).idxmax().reset_index()

   week  year      close      month        day    quarter
0    50  2016 2016-12-12 2016-12-16 2016-12-16 2016-12-16
1    50  2017 2016-12-12 2016-12-16 2016-12-16 2016-12-16
2    51  2016 2016-12-23 2016-12-23 2016-12-23 2016-12-23
3    51  2017 2016-12-23 2016-12-23 2016-12-23 2016-12-23
```